# cx_Freeze EXE application doesn't works on other computer

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I want to change a python script into an executable file.

The compilation is proceeding correctly and the executable works correctly on my computer.

The problem is that when I export the exe.win32-3.8 directory to another computer, the executable doesn't works. The execution window opens and closes immediately. The IE windows doesn't opens.

here is my setup.py :

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
# On appelle la fonction setup
setup(
   name = "CampaignRecovery",
   version = "0.1",
   description = "Ce programme recupère les campagnes depuis Opoci",
   executables = [Executable("CampaignRecovery.py")],
)
```

And my source code :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options

ieOptions = Options()
ieOptions.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True

browser = webdriver.Ie(options=ieOptions)
```

Could you, please help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup. not guarantee gonna work on your case, just to make sure you have python installed on target machine for testing purposes. and run it through CMD. from CMD you will able to tell what's wrong

```
import cx_Freeze 
import sys
import os


PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')


print(os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'],os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'])

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
syspath = r"C:\Python\DLLs"
buildOptions = dict(
    packages=["tkinter","pandas","numpy"],
    excludes=[],
    include_files=[('tcl86t.dll', os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),('tk86t.dll', os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll'))]
)
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("[YOUR APP].py", base=base, icon="hitek.ico")]
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "YOUR APP",
    options = dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
    version = "0.02",
    description = "YOUR APP",
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. I will keep it preciously. I had indeed a problem with the Internet Explorer driver and my pandas library. In fact my IS prevents the installation of win32com. In the end I went through pyInstaller and I bypassed the pandas library via a text file.